# Can not resolve removeAllPushNotificationsForDeviceRegistrationId() in PubNub.java

Tags: android, pubnub

I integrate pubnub's android sample code available, from [here](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android) 
but cant; able to resolve **removeAllPushNotificationsForDeviceRegistrationId()**
this method. 
 
I used this in build.gradle ->   compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.3'
from [here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need PubNub's Android SDK for that. Can you add this dependency instead?

```
com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.3
```

Here's the method in the source code

https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/8463441ca0322c90262bebde8b9975ccfcfb1cb9/android/src/com/pubnub/api/Pubnub.java#L335

Hope that helps.